# Plot different reactive graph using

Tags: r

I am currently trying to teach myself shiny, and am having a little trouble. I want to make an app that has a menu for which dataset the user would like to plot from, followed by another menu for which variable they would like to plot (against the date column)

I have managed to get the reactive menus working, but i am struggling to work out how to 'call' the selected dataset. I have read a lot of posts (e.g 1,2) but none seem to deal with the multiple dataset problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `base R` only.

```
fun <- function(x){
    sp <- unlist(strsplit(x, ";"))
    sp <- strsplit(sp, ":")
    sp <- unlist(lapply(sp, function(x) setNames(x[2], x[1])))
    sp[order(names(sp))]
}

result <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(dat, fun)))
row.names(result) <- NULL
result
#        city   name       tel
#1     London  Alyce 270167423
#2 Manchester Sabine 377658186
#3     Warsaw   John 182601043
#4       Brno   Alex 313976092
#5      Dehli    Tom 152764798
```

**DATA.**

```
dat <-
c("city:London;tel:270167423;name:Alyce", "tel:377658186;city:Manchester;name:Sabine", 
"city:Warsaw;name:John;tel:182601043", "city:Brno;tel:313976092;name:Alex", 
"name:Tom;tel:152764798;city:Dehli")
```